# How to prototype algorithm for running on android camera images?

Tags: android, jpeg, android-camera, augmented-reality

I have an idea for an Android app that relies on me processing images coming from the phone camera in realtime (think of the processing something like [Word Lens](http://questvisual.com/us/) has to do). I'd like to prototype my algorithm in Python by running it on static images, but I want the static images to match the format that would normally be received from an Android phone camera (I don't want to make a working algorithm for RGB and then find out Android's camera API gives you HSV byte arrays). Two questions:

1. What's the format? (or at least the most common, since Android hardware varies)
2. How do I convert my jpg test images to this format on Linux?

Comment: your link was dead, I changed it to http://questvisual.com/us/ for now. The video on that page demonstrates the app in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Android cameras are required to support two YUV formats, NV21, and YV12 (see [setPreviewFormat documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29)), for application-bound callbacks enabled by [setPreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29).

Some devices may support additional formats (RGB, YUYV2, etc), but those two are mandatory, so it's best to pick one of them. YV12 has a higher chance of being efficient, although that depends on the hardware in question.

As to the second, you can probably do the color conversion using some sort of utility program like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), but the other point about these formats is that they are sub-sampled for the chroma (color) planes; both NV21 and YV12 downsample the color formats by 2x in both dimensions.  For example, if the image size is 640x480, then the Y (luminance) channel will be 640x480, but the U and V channels are both only 320x240.  You'll probably need to do this subsampling yourself, since most image libraries don't expose that kind of a format (JPEG images are actually typically stored in a similar subsampled YUV format, but most libraries convert back to full RGB before giving you the data).

Edit: Additional notes

Alternatively, if your algorithm works well on the GPU, you could use the [setPreviewTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) path out of the camera, which lets you process the image data in a GPU shader. In that case, the data will always be RGB, accessed as a texture in an GLSL shader with OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: Why does YV12 have a higher chance of being efficient? Is that more often the hardware's native format?